# Considerations to take into account when clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, pca, normalization

My idea is to use clustering to perform stock segmentation based on risk, building different risk levels that might adapt better to different kind of users.

Hence I have computed different risk indicators as stock variance, VaR, loss probability and Sharpe Ratio. My final dataframe with SP&100 stocks looks like this: [image: Stocks' Risks]

I am wondering if I do need to have some considerations regarding data preprocessing since this variables are highly correlated, all of them are computed by a formulae that uses variance or standar deviation and mean returns.

I have been doing some research and found that I might need to perform data normalization and PCA analysis but I would like someone to explain me why in order to understand what I am doing and if I need to take any other considerations.

Comment: what are this variables in your question "this variables are highly correlated, ? Is it this or these variables- stock variance etc.

Comment: all of them are computed by a formulae that uses variance or standard deviation and mean returns. Clustering of variables based on common mathematical/statistical measures can not be appreciated. PCA simply helps in identifying key features.

Comment: continued ...Your apprehension is reasonable. You can select and try weighing of factors such as value at risk and expected return and volatility/annual variance.

Comment: normalization and PCA are unlikely to serve the goal you  have.